# Outlook macro / rule to automatically decline meeting invitations with end time beyond specified?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, calendar

I want to automatically decline the meeting requests for meetings that do not overlap with my work hours, say, 0900 to 1700 IST. The meeting requests may originate from other timezones. All other meeting requests must remain unaffected.

Few suggestions I found online and the reasons they couldn't fulfil the requirements:

- Create a recurring meeting and set outlook to auto decline conflicts: This affects meetings inside my work hours as well. I want to handle conflicts manually if inside my work hours.
- Create a rule that checks headers: Could not figure out how to handle timezones.

Good to have: Auto decline with the above rule only if the meeting request is received less than a specified number of hours in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have ever seen a similar micro there: [Autoaccept a Meeting Request using Rules](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/autoaccept-a-meeting-request-using-rules/)

You could try to edit it with your own requirement, and here is the script that I'm using :

```
Sub AcceptWorkingHours(oRequest As MeetingItem)
If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim oResponse
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
meetingtime = Format(oAppt.Start, "h:mm:ss AM/PM")

If meetingtime < #9:00:00 AM# Or meetingtime > #5:00:00 PM# Then

Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
oResponse.Send
oRequest.Close (olSave)
oRequest.Delete

End If
End Sub
```

Use it with Outlook rule(Action:Run a script), then we could automatically decline those meetings that start before 9:00 am or after 5:00 pm, and we could still manually manage the meetings in between. Hope it could also work for you :).

Comment: Hi Kaustubh Badrike,
Could it work for you?

Comment: Is there a way to sent auto decline but with message template? (for example "I'm in lunch. please set meeting for a bit later")

Comment: I found that depending on the type of response requested that the line `oResponse.Send` would sometimes fail.  If skipping that line, the meeting will still be declined (but I guess no response sent?).  I ended up just keeping that line, but catching any error and ignoring it